# Out of process server in VOIP

Tags: com, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10-universal

I found voip example on github for UWP. Now I'm trying to create my voip app, and I want to use VoipHost project in my app. I added existing project, edited package manifest file. When I want to deploy the app to the device I get error:

**Severity Code
Description Project
File Line
Suppression State Error
DEP6701 : Bootstrapping failed with unexpected error: 'The ID value is not specified. Parameter name: id'.
VoipHost**

And one warning:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1930,5): warning APPX1708: The executable 'VoipHost.exe' is specified as the implementation for the .winmd file. Only in-process servers are supported for generating registration information in the app manifest. You must specify the out-of-process server registration information in the app manifest.**

Any advices?
Many thanks.

Comment: Since this same post was created in Microsoft's forums I am posting a link to it. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/965b33c4-e9c0-43a1-b246-05ce85fc48f1/out-of-process-server-in-voip?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue deploying a headless application with Windows IoT running in a Raspberry pi 3. I solved the problem giving an "Assembly Identity" in the project properties.

You can do that following the next steps: Rigth Click to project --> Properties --> Manifest Tool --> General.

Fill the field "Assembly Identity" with any number. After that compiles, run and works like a charm.